# Xcode Command-Line Tools & Make

Tags: macos, xcode5

I have installed Xcode 5 on OS X Mavericks. I have a problem with the command-line tools (cc et al).

The version of cc in `/usr/bin` is outdated, so I’m not using it. The version of cc embedded deep within Xcode’s application bundle is current, so I’ve pasted the following code into my shell profile:

`` export PATH=`xcode-select -print-path`/usr/bin:`xcode-select -print-path`/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:${PATH} ``

This worked under Xcode 4 on Mountain Lion. Now, however, while the compiler *seems* to run fine when invoked as `cc`, it won’t compile anything when I invoke it that way; it apparently cannot find system headers (e.g. `stdio.h`). When I invoke the compiler as `xcrun cc`, everything works just fine. Unfortunately, this requires me to patch the inputs for each and every build-automation program (such as `make`) before they will run properly.

The other problem is that I cannot find the command-line tools for download from ADC. As I upgraded from Mountain Lion, invoking `/usr/bin/cc` does not ask me if I want to download the tools; it just runs the (outdated) copy of `cc` from Xcode 4.

What is the difference between `cc` and `xcrun cc`, and is there anything I can do that will cause `cc` to work properly from the Terminal (or automated build tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X 10.9 Mavericks, run `xcode-select --install` to update the installed command line tools so they match the version inside of Xcode.  This also installs header files into `/usr/include` and `/System/Library` and installs additional development libraries.  This is a change from previous versions of OS X where the command line tools were either installed via Xcode.app itself or by an Xcode installer.  It is still possible to download a standalone installer from the Apple Developer site but should normally no longer be necessary on 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with cc (although you will get better results if you use `clang` instead of `cc`. I suggest that you remove the program, download it again, and install the command line tools with `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Doesn't it have a different behavior if you invoke it as `cc` than if you invoke it as `clang`?

Comment: With Xcode 5, not that I know of.  But others may know more about it.